# database insert statement in PHP

Tags: php

I've simple script that store time/IP/PATH just how many online visitors script

```
$timeoutseconds= 50;
$timestamp=time();
$timeout=$timestamp-$timeoutseconds;
```

it will insert the following informations for any visitor time `$timestamp` `IP $REMOTE_ADDR` and Main Path `$PHP_SELF`

```
$sql= "insert into online VALUES ('$timestamp','$REMOTE_ADDR','$PHP_SELF')";
executeupdate($sql);
```

it will delete only if `timestamp<$timeout`

```
$sql= "delete from online WHERE timestamp<$timeout";
executeupdate($sql);
```

But this means if someone start making Zillions of reload for the page before `$timeout` ends will be counted over and over and over again !

so how can i modify it so that it depends on IP `$REMOTE_ADDR` and does not insert it if exist in order to repent repeating for same visitor since i'm willing to put it in footer which is in all pages of my website ! ~ thanks

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` includes the querystring. Sanitise it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that this question is very clear. I'm having trouble following it.

Comment: So you want to store the last connection from an IP address?

Comment: Reading your question again, I think I may have misunderstood it. Be warned that my solution still changes the database record for a particular IP address on every request, if any of the fields data for `timestamp` and/or `page` is different than the values that are already in the record for that IP address. It will however not create new records for every request from the same IP, it will merely update the record (if necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL, make the ip field the primary key, and use this query:

```
$sql= "
    INSERT INTO
        online
    VALUES
        ('$REMOTE_ADDR','$timestamp','$PHP_SELF')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `timestamp` = '$timestamp',
        `page` = '$PHP_SELF'
";
```

(This is assuming the following column names: `ip`, `timestamp`, `page`)

By the way, you should protect against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), if you aren't doing so already. Don't insert external data verbatim in your database. But use proper escaping mechanisms; preferably parameterized prepared statements. This [can be done](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add UNIQUE constraint on $REMOTE_ADDR.

1. If you need update some fields for this key you can use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
2. If you needn't to update anything run INSERT IGNORE INTO ....

Answer (score 0):

use UPDATE instead of INSERT

```
$sql= "UPDATE online SET timestampColumnName ='$timestamp' WHERE remoteColumnName ='$REMOTE_ADDR'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think more detail would be helpful,  but you can influence what gets stored using indexes.  If you only want one hit per IP, you can add a unique index on the ip column. To store the most recent hit from the IP you can then add on duplicate key update to the end of the query. For a situation where you want to force an interval, the best option would probably be to do a select first - select max(timestamp) where ip = '$ip' - if there is no result, log the hit,  otherwise check the time.